# How to use generic type in a value tuple?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, tuples, derived-class

Let's presume i have two enums:

```
    public enum eFruits : int
    {
        Apple = 1,
        Pear = 2,
        Banana = 3
    }
```

```
    public enum eAnimals : int
    {
        Dog = 1,
        Cat = 2,
        Rabbit = 3
    }
```

I would like to use these in dropdownlists/checklists etc; basically as listitems. The current code i have as a tryout is this;

```
    public static class EnumHelper
    {     
        public static IEnumerable<(int eCode, eFruits eType)> GetFruitTypesAsListItems()
        {
            var enums = new List<(int eCode, eFruits eType)>();
            foreach (var item in (eFruits[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(eFruits)))
            {
                enums.Add(((int)item, item));
            }
            return enums;
        }
    }
```

Two issues with this;

1) I would like to have this in a generic way

2) It doesn't look nice inside a list/dropdown etc. so I'd like to use a ToString override.

Therefore I thought of something like this:

```
    public class EnumListItem : Tuple<int, T>
    {
        public EnumListItem(int eCode, T eType) 
            : base(eCode, eType)
        { }

        public override string ToString() => $"{base.Item2.ToString()} ({base.Item1})";
    }
```

So in effect;

1) I would like to use a Generic with a Tuple

2) Would like to use a Generic to be able to generate list items based on that Tuple

Is this possible? I'm not sure how the declaration of this would look like. At this point I can't get it to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below generic method.

```
public static class EnumHelper<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<(int eCode, T eType)> GetListItem()
    {
        var enums = new List<(int eCode, T eType)>();
        foreach (var item in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            enums.Add((Convert.ToInt32(item), item));
        }
        return enums;
    }
}
```

And you can call it like,

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var animals = EnumHelper<eAnimals>.GetListItem();

    var fruits = EnumHelper<eFruits>.GetListItem();
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple to make it a generic function. And you could use `yield` to return a generator enumerable instead of a buffered `List` to get rid of unnecessary use of memory.

```
public static IEnumerable<(int, TEnum)> GetValues<TEnum>()
where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
    {
        yield return ((int)item, (TEnum)item);
    }
}
```